# How can I covert Spring Boot app to normal Spring (regarding autowired beans)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired

I am trying to convert spring boot app to spring, but I am getting NullPointerException for autowired beans.

I have an `applicationContext.xml` file, but I think SpringBoot was reading it by default and it is not getting read anymore.

How can this be avoided?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Having said that, it might be helpful to have a [mcve] - a really small example that shows your problem. I am pretty sure that Spring itself supports annotation processing as well, so this very much looks like you are not configuring the spring setup correctly.

Comment: I was missing web.xml somehow my applicationContext.xml was not called. But now it is called , however still autowired classes throw nullpointerexception. Is there any way I can share my code in zip?

Answer (score 0):

Once spring boot is removed from the application, then all spring configuration is lost, I mean there is no dependency injection. So you need to manually configure the spring dispatcher servlet to read a spring-config.xml where you should declare all your dependencies. For example, edit `web.xml` as below to let your application load the spring config

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>springMvcDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

Then configure your spring-config.xml for dependency injection

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mybatis="http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
        http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring
        http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dept.security" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dept.best.controllers" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dept.best.facades" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dept.best.facades.business" />


</beans>
```

This is just one example, you could also do it java configuration of spring. I just converted an application running using Spring boot 2.5.3.Release version to a plain spring-mvc application. After several updates and fixes, not it works fine.